# position Absolute div at bottom of an Absolute positioned parent div

Tags: css

I have my "header_main" positioned absolute with a height of 100% to basically cover the entire screen. Inside the header_main div n have another div  positioned absolute as well. I have set the "icon-wrapper" div to bottom:0; but it does not want to position absolute bottom.

```
<body id="top" class="no-js">
<header id="header_main">
   <div class="icon-wrapper"></div>
</header>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body{
  font: 18px/27px $font-stack;
  color: $text-color;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#header_main{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('../images/ac-placeholder-img.jpg') no-repeat center center;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
.icon-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    height: 254px;
    bottom: 0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by giving top:100%; to the icon wrapper it will be always to the bottom of the header_main check out the working demo below;

```css
#header_ main{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  background:#ddd;

}
.icon-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    height: 254px;
    bottom: 0;
  background:red;
  
  top:100%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<body id="top" class="no-js"> <header id="header_main"> Scroll Down<div class="icon-wrapper">ww</div> </header> </body>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

`.icon-wrapper` is being aligned to the bottom, but its content is not, because the display value of absolute-positioned elements [**is always `table` or `block`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo), and `vertical-align` [**applies to `inline` or `table-cell` elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)  only.

Use the wrapper for the absolute positioning only, and add another element to handle the vertical align:

**CSS**

```
.icon-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.icon {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 254px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpfmd4rr/1)**

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the width for the absolute positioned div.

```
.icon-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    height: 254px;
    bottom: 0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @GavinWood Yes you do..otherwise it will have no width other than that defined by the content of the div.